# SHA1 certificate key on windows 10

Tags: openssl, windows-10, sha1, google-developers-console

I am trying to create a OAuth client ID with google developer. I need to generate a Signing-certificate fingerprint. I am on windows 10 and have installed JDK. when I am using following command then nothing happens in command prompt.

```
"C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary
```

Following command works but the output is not whats needed by google.

```
"C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.exe" base64
```

Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by installing Git bash and using command `openssl rand -base64 32 | openssl sha1 -c`